# How to append dictionary to json file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary

I have a Json file looks like this:

```
{"user": ["file1","file2"],"user2": ["file1"]}
```

I want to append a dictionary

```
{u'user2': [u'file2'],u'user3': [u'file1'], u'user4': [u'file1']}
```

in the json file so that json file should look like

`{"user": ["file1","file2"],"user2": ["file1", "file2"],"user3": ["file1"],"user4": ["file1"]}`

from my current aproach

```
with open ('jsonfile', 'a+') as json_file :
   json.dump(dictionary, json_file)
```

im getting json file like:

```
{"user": ["file1","file2"]}{"user2": ["file1", "file2"]}{"user3": ["file1"]}{"user4": ["file1"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
d1 = {"user": ["file1","file2"],"user2": ["file1"]}
d2 = {u'user2': [u'file2'],u'user3': [u'file1'], u'user4': [u'file1']}

for k, v in d2.items():
    d1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
print(d1)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'user4': [u'file1'], 'user2': ['file1', u'file2'], 'user': ['file1', 'file2'], u'user3': [u'file1']}
```

Comment: but in my case d1 is a json file.